# Confidence interval: how to show that a given mean is plausible or not?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I am going through some questions as practice for my  STATS examination and I am baffled with one question pertaining confidence intervals. There are three parts to this question, I can do parts (a) and (b), however I am stuck with part (c). Below is the question:
[image: question]
My solutions to parts (a) and (b) are as follows:
[image: solutionab]
Could somebody please assist me with (c) or at least explain what am I supposed to do? It would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: From the image of your solution that you posted, it seems that you know how to use MathJax or something equivalent.  Please use MathJax when posting here instead of uploading images.  This makes the text searchable and the page load faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct a 95% confidence interval, it gives an interval with plausible values at 5%. To see whether the mean is plausible or not, you simply have to see whether the mean is in the interval. If the mean is in the interval, then it is a plausible value.

Comment: @MadhavNaker so basically if the interval is $101<x<107$ and the mean is 130 than it is not plausible. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: You may also express your gratitude by upvoting the answer.